# Hiding Text in Word (particularly tables)

Tags: vba, ms-word, visibility

I've been working on a document that has a number of hidden sections that can be made visible using check boxes (and VBA).  Most of this works fine including hiding Tables, Pictures, Formatting and Text using Range.Font.Hidden = True.

My problem lies with leaving a table hidden, saving the document and then re-opening the document.

The document saves and closes fine, but when reopening the Document the text for the table stays hidden but the table gridlines and spacing are displayed, giving the look of a strange but empty table.

Does anyone know of a way to avoid this problem or have any advice?

Comment: I'm currently testing it on 2007 with both a 2007 Macro Enabled Document and a 2003 Document file.

Comment: I can't recreate in Word 2003.  ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Font.Hidden = True (or False) works fine when saving and reopening.  Do you have anything in the Document_Open() method?

Comment: No code in Document_Open and hidding the table seems to work fine until I reopen the document.  Then I get the same borders still showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a number of different things and even though I have other sections that contain tables that work fine, I have ended up converting the tables back to text which makes them work fine.

It is annoying that I can't seem to find the issue, but the information works out ok just as normal text.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the gridlines like so:

```
ActiveWindow.View.TableGridlines = False
```

However, it won't work if your table has custom borders.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately yes we use drawn borders.